# displaying JSON onto Html - Angular 4

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular, web-services

I have JSON data that I can read and access in console. I need to read onto Html. But it looks like I can't read. I get an error saying that cannot read property of NewDataSet. Anyone has ideas?  I am not sure if data is returning from mpa function to subscribe.

**html**

```
<div>{{results.NewDataSet.Table[0]}}</div>
```

**sample data when returning res in service.ts **

[image]

Comment: If your `console.log` is for `results`, then you just want `results.Table[0]`

Comment: it still has errors : " cannot read property Table of undefined "

Comment: Try `results?.Table[0]`, as it will be undefined until the service returns

Comment: Please refer to updated sample data. that's what I see when I log res. That still doesn't output anything without error.

Comment: Bear in mind that, whatever is done in the `.do` function will not change what is received by the calling controller. You may want to add `.map(res => res.json())` after your `do` function

Comment: can i just replace .do with .map?

Comment: As long as you return res

Comment: so i replaced with map and returned it (updated in question as well). but still gives me same error

Comment: That's because your not returning res from `.map`, you're returning it from the callback in `parseString`

Comment: I thought as long as I include parseString in map , it will return res as well?..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157159/discussion-between-user184994-and-james).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div>{{results?.NewDataSet?.Table[0] | json}}</div>
```

Instead of

```
<div>{{results.NewDataSet.Table[0]}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your html page will rendered before your data populates by rest call response. 
in that scenario your  **results** variable is empty array without **NewDataSet**

```
results: any [];
```

so declare as object and create array as element of that object

```
results: any = { NewDataSet : {
                                  Table : []
                               } 
               };
```

Change your declaration like this.

Comment: it gives me an error : cannot read property newdataset of undefined

Comment: in results.NewDataSet.Table , Table array containts String ?